# Formik + Yup - Show error as user is typing in

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, formik, yup

I have an email field and I am validating its uniqueness as the user types in i.e is the email the user is typing available. Currently, I only get the error message when the user loses focus of the field (onBlur) but I want formik to show errors while the user is typing in. I've read that showing errors on losing focus on the field is the 'default' behavior of formik but I was hoping maybe there was a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Formik's `validateOnChange` prop to trigger validations on every change event

See [here](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#when-does-validation-run) for details

Comment: I believe they're both set to true by default. Changing their values did not work for me.